# Unknown types with moving from 10.4 to 10.8 SDK

Tags: xcode, macos, compiler-construction, llvm, typedef

I have an older project that works on Xcode 3.2.6 and the 10.4u SDK...

When moving it to the 10.8 SDK and LLVM 5, I am getting some unknown types:

Errors:

```
Error: unknown type name 'Handle'
    typedef Handle OSMenuBar; // Handle to Mac Menu Bar
            ^
```

Here is the code:

```
#if TARGET_OS_MAC
    typedef Handle                  OSMenuBar;                 // Handle to Mac Menu Bar
    typedef MenuRef                 OSMenu;                    // Opaque reference to Mac Menu
    typedef WindowRef               OSWindow;                  // Opaque reference to Mac Window
    typedef Handle                  OSHandle;                  // Mac Handle
    typedef ControlRef              OSControl;                 // Opaque reference to Mac Control
    typedef Ptr                     OSPtr;                     // Mac memory Ptr
    typedef SInt16                  OSFileRef;                 // Mac file reference number
    typedef IconRef                 OSIconRef;                 // Mac IconRef
    typedef FSVolumeRefNum          OSVolume;                  // Mac volume ref num
    typedef WindowClass             OSWindowClass;             // Mac WindowClass

    typedef CGContextRef            OSCGContextRef;            // Mac Quartz context ref

    typedef DataBrowserItemID       OSDataBrowserItemID;       // DataBrowser item id
    typedef DataBrowserPropertyID   OSDataBrowserPropertyID;   // DataBrowser property id
    typedef DataBrowserItemDataRef  OSDataBrowserItemDataRef;  // DataBrowserItemDataRef

#pragma warning "TODO -- No QuickDraw for what OS 10.5???"
    typedef GrafPtr                 OSGraphicsPort;            // Mac GrafPtr
    typedef GWorldPtr               OSImageList;               // Mac GWorld containing images
    typedef CIconHandle             OSColorIcon;               // Mac CIcon
    typedef Handle                  OSIconSuite;               // Mac Icon Suite Handle
    typedef PicHandle               OSPicture;                 // Mac Picture Handle
    typedef RgnHandle               OSRegion;                  // Mac Region
#endif
```

All of these TypeDefs seem to produce the same unknown type error.

How do I best solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like you have an old Carbon project - Carbon is deprecated in 10.8 I believe.

Comment: Indeed it is an old Carbon Project! So does that mean 10.7 only? And there needs to be a getting away from Carbon coding marathon? And does this mean we have to start using Objective-C?

Comment: I'm not sure what your options are at this point, but you could first try setting your SDK to something earlier - I'm not sure how far back the current version of Xcode supports though. Note that Xcode 3.2.x still works fine on OS X 10.8 (I still use it for old projects),

Comment: Can one still be on 10.6 and XCode 3.2.6, targeting the 104U or 10.5 SDK and the app still run on 10.9 though? Since the app is build and linked on a platform that still has carbon?

Comment: I'm not sure - I guess Carbon apps still run on 10.8 (?) so as long as you can build against an older SDK then it should work. I can only suggest you try it and see.

Comment: True, this app does run on 10.8 fine using the 10.4u SDK